# Opening Browser on push notification

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

I am trying to open the browser with a url when the user click on the push notification, i search in stackoverflow and i find this

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
```

but it doesnt work for me, when i put that the notification doesnt appear, i debugged it and it only throw the class file editor no error or anything.

this is the code

```
   public void mostrarNotificacion(Context context, String body,String title, String icon, String url,String superior)
{

    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager notManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);




    int icono = R.drawable.mydrawable;
    CharSequence textoEstado = superior;
    long hora = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Notification notif = new Notification(icono, textoEstado, hora);


    Context contexto = context.getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence titulo = title;
    CharSequence descripcion = body;
    PendingIntent contIntent;
    if(url.equalsIgnoreCase("NULL"))
    {
        Intent notIntent = new Intent(contexto,MainActivity.class);
        contIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                contexto, 0, notIntent, 0);
    }
    else
    {            
        // Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         //i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        // contIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(contexto, 0, i, 0);   
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(browserIntent);



    }


   // notif.setLatestEventInfo(contexto, titulo, descripcion, contIntent);



    //AutoCancel: 
    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;


    //send notif
    notManager.notify(1, notif);
}
```

Comment: Where do you call the `mostrarNotificacion` method?

Comment: Its working now thanks to dror fichman, anyway i call the method onMessage

Comment: Here is a workaround http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39285006/android-lock-screen-notification-is-not-able-to-open-browser-on-double-tapping

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What you need to do is set a pending intent - 
which will be invoked when the user clicks the notification. 
(Above you just started an activity...)

Here's a sample code :

```
private void createNotification(String text, String link){

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
    .setContentTitle(text);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // pending implicit intent to view url
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    resultIntent.setData(Uri.parse(link));

    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pending);

    // using the same tag and Id causes the new notification to replace an existing one
    mNotificationManager.notify(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()), PUSH, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

**Edit 1 :**
I changed the answer to use `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` for the sample purpose. Thanks Aviv Ben Shabat for the comment.

**Edit 2 :**
Following  Alex Zezekalo's comment, note that **opening the notification from the lock screen, assuming chrome is used, will fail** as explained in the open issue : https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=455126 -
Chrome will ignore the intent, and you should be able to find in your logcat - 
E/cr_document.CLActivity﹕ Ignoring intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://google.com/... flg=0x1000c000 cmp=com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main (has extras) }

Comment: Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK should not be used here. As it says in the docs: 
Must be one or more of: PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT,  Intent.FILL_IN_ACTION, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA, Intent.FILL_IN_CATEGORIES...)

Comment: Hmm, it's a good solution but it doesn't work when I tap on push notification on Lock screen: in that case browser doesn't run and doesn't  open link. Any idea?

Comment: Hi @AlexZezekalo, was able to reproduce your issue. At first I thought it was a matter of implicit/explicit intent, since using pending intent to start a specific activity works well. But than I saw that chrome logs : Ignoring intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://google.com/... flg=0x1000c000 cmp=com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main. - I got to the chrome issue (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=455126) that explains why they are ignoring the intent. No workaround I can think of..