# Open a website link upon clicking on push notification in Android Phone

Tags: node.js, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-plugins

we are using phonegap cordova , node-gcm for sending push notification . Actually our mobile application is not completed it have login screen , so upon login successfully we send device toke to server . So we want that when we send push notification it opens the browser and redirects to the link , it is possible ?

Node Code

```
var gcm = require('node-gcm');
var message = new gcm.Message();

//API Server Key
var sender = new gcm.Sender('ccxxxcdddd');
var registrationIds = [];

sender.send(message, registrationIds, 4, function (a,result) {

    console.log("ok",a);
    console.log("result",result);

});
```

So basically we wants to open the particular link in browser upon clicking of push notification . We receive push notifications in mobile but upon clicking it open the app

Comment: I believe you should create redirect function in your app. Since push always open app

Comment: no I think it is possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16526369/opening-browser-on-push-notification

Comment: You have to code needed, you'll have to edit the push plugin to include that

Answer (score 0):

We use `window.open('http://www.kidzout.com', '_system');` to solve this problem . App is running in pause state and without opening the app it directly open the browser