# Unable to receive notification in Battery optimization mode Pushy

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, notifications, pushy

I am using pushy for sending notification in my android app but there is a problem with that, if the mobile is in battery optimization mode, pushy will not be able to send the notifications.
But using firebase you can still receive notifications even if your phone is on battery optimization (As far as I tested),

But the problem here is, that firebase uses play services in order to send notifications, and I don't wanna use play services, Is there any other solution that can be used to push notifications without play services that also handles the battery optimization problem.

I have tried using hivemq that uses MQtt to send messages but wasn't able to work around with this cuz we still have to create a service to keep the connection alive but on battery optimization mode services are killed, hope you guys can suggest better solutions.